# Bash string contains a number other than 0

Tags: bash

I have a bash command that outputs something similar to this. There are lines above and below it.

```
> ...  
> server1 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0  
> server2 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0  
> server3 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0  
> ...
```

I am trying to determine whether in any of those output anything other than **changed=0** it does not matter which one, just determine if the output contained any other number than **0** after the **changed=**

This is about the best i got, but obviously would not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output=`mycommand`

if [[ $output != *"changed=0"* ]]; then
  # Run more code here
fi
```

Comment: `mycommand | grep -v 'changed=0'`

Comment: It accepts a wildcard, it accepts a regex if you use the `=~` form, so something like `[[ $output =~ changed=[1-9] ]]` should match if there's a line matching `changed=` followed by any of the digits from `1-9`

Comment: Thanks @Petesh it's apparently `=~` instead of `~=` but that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways to determine this. Assuming you're just looking for any string changed=<a digit other than 0> then you could use:

```
if [[ $output =~ changed=[1-9] ]]; then
    echo "work"
fi
```

You can test for the presence of text *after* filtering out the changed=0 lines:

```
filtered=$(echo "$output" | grep -v 'changed=0')
if [[ -n $filtered ]]; then
    echo "work"
fi
```

however this does not work if you have lines other than ones with changed, so you can do:

```
filtered=$(echo "$output" | grep 'changed=' | grep -v 'changed=0')
if [[ -n $filtered ]]; then
    echo "work"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about what you mean by "different than changed=0": do you mean by that "changed=x", where x can be any value between 1 and 9 (are negative numbers possible, and what about floating point numbers)? Or do you mean that "changed=false", "changed=true" are also ok?

In case you are looking for the case "changed=x" with x between 1 and 9, you might go for the regular expression:

```
changed=[1-9]
```

In case you are looking for the case where anything but "changed=0" is ok, you might go for:

```
grep -v "changed=0"
```

In case there  are other cases possible (negative numbers, floating point numbers, ...), please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
res=$(echo "$output" | grep -P "changed=[^0]")
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  # Run more code here
fi
```